# Uncaught Type Error : operation.match is not a function

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I am trying to get a user Input and turn that into an array of string to my token. For some reason it is not working.

**For Example :** Compute(5*6+7) should give token = ["5","**","6","+","7"]

```js
function splitOperation(operation) {
return operation.match(/(\d+(\.\d+)?|[+\-*/])/g);
}
  

function Compute(userInput) {
    let token = [splitOperation(userInput)];
    
    }
    
let userInput = 5*6+7
Compute(userInput)
```

Comment: Based on your expected result, remove the brackets around `[splitOperation(userInput)]` and follow the answer below.

Comment: There is no `Number.prototype.match`. There is only a [`String.prototype.match`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

5*6+7 is a number.

To use "match" you need a string, use "5*6+7", if your regex is good, this should do it.

Comment: For more details on match, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match